# Check if a condition is true if so proceed to next level if not throw an alert message

Tags: javascript, html

So currently i have 2 draggable images and two Div boxes. You can drag the images into the Div boxes and depending on what image you drop into a particular Div the border colour of that Div will change (green or red).

What i want to do next is to have a button lets say "Next" that when you click on this button it will take you to another page BUT only if both DIV boxes have green borders, if this criteria  isn't met then an alert should pop up. Sounds really weird i know but help would be very much appreciated :).

My code is below:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="Drop1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </div>
<div id="Drop2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </div>
<img src="trash.jpg" ondrop="drop(event)"     ondragover="allowDrop(event)" id="trash" draggable="false"/>

<img id="drag1" class="item1" src="forward.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="64" height="64">
<img id="drag2" class="item2" src="left.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="64" height="64">

<button onclick="checkImages()">Validate images</button>
```

CSS:

```
#Drop1 {width:70px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid#aaaaaa;}
#Drop2 {width:70px;height:70px;padding:10px;border:1px solid#aaaaaa;}

#Drop1.red-border,
#Drop2.red-border {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#Drop1.green-border,
#Drop2.green-border {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#Drop1.gray-border,
#Drop2.gray-border {
  border: 1px solid darkgray;
}
```

JS:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
 ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text/html");

    var clone = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = clone.id + (new Date()).getMilliseconds();
    ev.target.appendChild(clone);

    if (ev.target == document.getElementById("trash")) {
        var img = document.getElementById(data);
        img.parentNode.removeChild(img); 
    }
}

function checkImages() {
  var drop1Elem = document.getElementById('Drop1'),
      drop2Elem = document.getElementById('Drop2');

  if(drop1Elem.childNodes.length >= 1) {
    if(drop1Elem.childNodes[0].className === 'item1') {
      drop1Elem.className = 'red-border';
    } else if(drop1Elem.childNodes[0].className === 'item2') {
      drop1Elem.className = 'green-border';
    } else {
      drop1Elem.className = 'gray-border';
    }
  }

  if(drop2Elem.childNodes.length >= 1) {
    if(drop2Elem.childNodes[0].className === 'item1') {
      drop2Elem.className = 'red-border';
    } else if(drop2Elem.childNodes[0].className === 'item2') {
      drop2Elem.className = 'green-border';
    } else {
      drop2Elem.className = 'gray-border';
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you wrote, maybe something like this.

HTML:

```
<button onclick="greenCheck()">Next</button>
```

JS:

```
function greenCheck() {
    var drop1Elem = document.getElementById('Drop1'),
    drop2Elem = document.getElementById('Drop2');

    if (drop2Elem.className == 'green-border' && drop1Elem.className == 'green-border') {
    // Next page
    } else {
    // Tell user both of them are not green
}
```

I'm assuming you did `checkImages()` which assigns the css classes here.